# Significant decimal digits of double?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, language-lawyer

What does the C/C++-Standard guarantee about the minimum significant decimal digits of a `double`?

The C++ standard actually says in a footnote of § 18.3.2.4/10 this is equivalent to `DBL_DIG` as defined in the C standard.  But I can't find anything about a minimum value in the C standard.

So, what is the minimum value of one of the following?

- `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`
- `DBL_MANT_DIG` edit: No, `DBL_DIG`

Comment: Interesting, I was wondering the same earlier when I read a similar question, and I couldn't find anything in the standards. As far as I know, it's only guaranteed that the three floating point types have nested ranges.

Comment: The section you want is §5.2.4.2.2 in the C standard. It's a rather interesting section, content-wise, but you'll have to wait for someone less lazy than me to come along to extract anything meaningful. :) Does seem to have a bit where it gives minimal requirements, but I only glanced over it.

Comment: Just checked the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) which, in section 5.2.4.2.2 paragraph 10, says "The values given in the following list shall be replaced by constant expressions with implementation-deﬁned values that are greater or equal in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign:" - but then doesn't show any value for `DBL_MANT_DIG` either.

Comment: From the definition: DBL_MANT_DIG specifies the number of base FLT_RADIX digits in the mantissa part of a double.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe It makes no sense to specify a minimum for `DBL_MANT_DIG`, since as byteherder says, it depends on `FLT_RADIX`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: `DBL_MANT_DIG` needs to be at least `ceil(DBL_DIG * log<sub>FLT_RADIX</sub>10)`, i.e., the number digits needed to represent enough digits to cover `DBL_DIG` (I may have screwed up the formula, though).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You won't find it in the C++ standard, because C++ defers to the C standard on this one.  For decimal digits, the minimum values are:

```
FLT_DIG   6
DBL_DIG  10
LDBL_DIG 10
```

So, 6 digits for `float`, and 10 for `double` and `long double`.  (This is the number of digits for which it is guaranteed that a conversion from text to the type and back will result in the same value.)

Note that `DBL_MANT_DIG` corresponds to the number of digits in the base, thus usually the number of binary digits, and not the number of decimal digits.

Comment: `DBL_DIG` is not the same as `DBL_MANT_DIG`, which is what the OP asked for?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I noticed that afterwards.  He asked first for
`std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`, however, which 
corresponds to `DBL_DIG`.  The standard makes no requirements on
`DBL_MANT_DIG`, since the significance of the value depends on
`FLT_RADIX`.  An IBM `float` (with `FLT_RADIX == 16`) would only
be 6, where as a IEEE `float` would have 24, although they
aren't that radically different in precision.

Comment: I made a mistake, `DBL_DIG` was the definition I searched for.

Comment: See :  §5.2.4.2.2 in the standard

Comment: @helami That's what I suspected, given your reference to `digits10` in `numeric_limits`.

Comment: @jimmcnamara That's what I was looking at when I posted.  In fact, the part that shows up as a code block was copy-pasted from my copy of ISO 9899::1999.

Comment: @jameskanze - that paragraph is the same for c11 apparently - at least the version I have from Dec 2011.

Comment: @jimmcnamara I'm also pretty sure it was the same in C90, although I'm too lazy to get my paper copy out.  There's no real reason for it to change.  (I chose my version of C99 because that's the version the C++ standard refers to.)